# How do I select a value not associated with another value?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

One of the questions asks what physicians have NOT treated Patient No. 3249. (Hint SELECT ... NOT IN ...)

I currently have a table setup with the physician_id and the patient_no. I can figure out what physicians have worked with Patient 3249 but I have no clue how to figure out what physicians haven't worked with them. The hint says use SELECT ... NOT IN ... but I haven't been able to make it work and haven't found anything online to help.

Any suggestions or pointers?

Comment: I wouldn't use NOT IN for this although you could. I would prefer to use NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Did you mean to tag both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: It would look something like `SELECT DISTINCT physician_id FROM yourtable WHERE physician_id NOT IN (SELECT physician_ID FROM yourtable WHERE patient_id = 3249);` Essentially: "Select the physicians that have never worked on this one patient". To @SeanLange very good point, this query would be better as a `NOT EXISTS` where that subquery was correlated  on `physician_id`, but perhaps that's next chapter.

Comment: You are right with the sub-select there JNevill!

Comment: What queries have you actually tried?   Also, like @DaleK (I like how it looks like Dalek) mentioned, did you mean to tag both SQL Server and MySQL?  Are you doing this in both?   They're not one in the same.

Comment: I did not mean to tag both; I am just doing it in MySQL.

Comment: @JNevill that worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give X is a query that gives you all IDs of physicians that worked on the patient
then

```
  SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE physician_id not in (x)
```

would give you the others.

That is what the hint means.

Of course you can also use a left join here

```
  SELECT *
  FROM Table
  LEFT JOIN (x) AS X ON x.physician_id = Table.physician_id
  WHERE x.physician_id is null
```

which in some cases is faster than `not in`, depending on stuff.  Both of these queries get the same result.

Comment: books could be written @WOUNDEDStevenJones (and have been but can be summarized as -- for small sets of data use not in for larger sets use indexes and left joins)

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use `group by` and `having`:

```
select physician_id
from treatments t
group by phsyician_id
having sum(patient_id = 3249) = 0;
```

Of course, this gets only physicians who have ever treated *any* patient but that seems reasonable in the real world.

Comment: They should invite you as a guest lecturer